# Disabling double tap for Listview

Tags: android

I have a listview inside a fragment. when I double tap on any item of the listview then the app is crashing. Can anyone suggest how to disable double tap on listview?

Comment: Can you show the codes.

Comment: Please update your code.

Comment: show your DoubleTap Listener code and logcat

Comment: @abhisekh-tripathy Can you show us your code and also post the logcat when its crashing?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `Boolean` Variable `isClicked = true`

and in your `onItemSelectedListener` of `ListView` you can do this

```
if(isClicked){
   //run your code here
    isClicked==false;
}else{
   isClicked==true;
}
```